# how to makefile with iostream, string and ifstream library

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to build a makefile for an application that use the lib string iostream and fstream.that's what I did up to now

```
       CPP      = gcc
       LIB_DIR      = ./incl
       PROGRAMS = test
       PROGS_O      = action_rec.o
       CPPFLAGS = -I$(LIB_DIR) -pg -g
       VPATH        = ./src/
       OBJFILES = $(VPATH)$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
       LIBS     = -02 -liostream -lfstream -lstdlib -lstring
```

when I try to use my makefile I get as result that everything that need the lib string fstream and iostream was not declared, while everything that need the lib stdlib works properly.
can someone tell me why?
thank you

Comment: are you sure that LIBS variable passed to compiler?

Comment: You need to `#include <iostream>` in the source file that needs it. You should not pass that as linker arguments, they are not libraries. (Unless you're using something non-standard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try taking all the -lstring -stdlib -liostream -lfstream out and see if it fixes it.

And compile with g++ so it finds other things it needs to link C++ code.

Comment: `iostream` is **not** in libc; it's normally in a library which comes with the compiler (`libstdc++`) in the case of `gcc`.  But if you link using `g++`, it will add this in automatically.

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate issues here.

The C++ side:
Don't use the `gcc` binary for compiling C++ code - use `g++` instead. This will pull in all the required standard include paths and libraries automagically.

The Makefile side:
Your Makefile has a number of issues:

1. Don't set `CPP` to a compiler; this variable defines the preprocessor to use. Use `CXX` to define the compiler - it most likely happens to be defined to `g++` anyway.
2. Don't create programs with the name `test`. This happens to clash with a standard Unix program (`/usr/bin/test`) and if you don't pay attention you might end up calling the wrong program.
3. Don't pass `-02` as the linker flags via `LIBS`. This switch is a) wrongly worded (it should be `-O2`, the letter O not a zero) and b) it's a compiler flag, so it should be part of `CXXFLAGS`.
4. Chances are that you don't need a Makefile at all. The make program comes with default Makefiles so often you can just create a `main.cpp` file and then run

   ```
   make main
   ```

   This will automatically compile and link `main.cpp` into a `main` executable. In your case, something like

   ```
   CXXFLAGS="-I./incl -pg -g -O2" make main
   ```

   Might be sufficient.

Comment: Huge +1: I've been using GNU make for more years than I can remember and I did not know that you could run it without rolling your own Makefile! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that you're linking with `gcc` rather than `g++`.
`gcc` doesn't link against the C++ standard library.  You can add it
manually, but the simplest is simply to use `g++` for everything (unless
you have actual C code; `g++` will compiler files ending in `.c` as
C++).

Answer (score 0):

`LIBS     = -02 -liostream -lfstream -lstdlib -lstring` can be simplified a lot. Just use `LIBS = -O2` (I think you meant -O2 rather than -02.) In fact, you really shouldn't be passing a `-O` flag to the link stage at all. Optimization is a compile-time option, not a link-time option.

Comment: `-O2` should rather go into `CPPFLAGS` then in LIBS.

Comment: @RedX: `-O2` is a compiler flag, not a preprocessor flag, so it should go into `CXXFLAGS`.